# Shell Script - how to replace first line string with empty string?

Tags: shell

I would like to replace first line with empty string in shell script?

For example:

**Input**

```
Skipping HTTPS certificate checks altogether. Note that this is not secure at all. 
Line 2 ......
Line 3 ......
```

**Output**

```
Line2
Line3
```

What Unix command I can use to perform same? Any Idea?

Comment: your input and output are from files or command outputs?

Comment: Looks like that first line is there for a reason! Anyway, do you want to delete the contents of the line or remove it altogether? What have you tried here and where are you stuck?

Comment: This is from command output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below also

```
yourcommand | awk 'NR>1'
```

or

```
yourcommand | tail -n+2
```

Comment: Is there any problem in #1? Let me know the issue. I will correct it.

Comment: I didn't try first one. I just used second one.

Answer (score 1):

if it's in a file, you can use this to delete the first line :

```
sed -i '1d' ../file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I was looking to apply it on string which is returned by command.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, that you want Output to be basically equal to Input, but the first line being delted? This is is done with the Unix command 'tail'.

From the man page of tail:

```
    -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output starting with
          the Kth
```

Comment: My input is coming from another command and I want to delete first line from that input.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer

Comment: Many things: answer normally explain how to do something and then do it, eventually showing some kind of output. This just a comment about how to do it.

Comment: @fedorqui: Maybe I misunderstood the question then. I thought that the OP wanted to know, whether there is already a standard command doing this job, so I told him the name of the command. Figuring out the usage is trivial (it's just supplying the correct parameters, which can be seen from the man-pages). But if you think it is better to provide this information explicitly, I can of course add it.....

Comment: I think it is best to provide a complete answer. Otherwise many questions could be answered with a mere "check man -command-"

Comment: @fedorqui: Indeed, this is the case in many forums I know (but it seems to be different here), maybe because people became annoyed by posters who are just to lazy to have a look at the docs. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: This is a true point. Note that many questions become closed exctly because of that. See [ask] for more info. Then, as a good question can be "assumed", a good answer can come. Interesting infos: [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy experience in SO!